# Film about space vampires

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon, vampire

I remember watching an animated film 20+ years ago about vampires in space but can't seem to find out the name of it or who made it. Remember one scene where a character gets sucked out an airlock and explodes, only to then reform in space.

Any ideas?

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: That was a full-fledged film? Not an animated series?

Comment: @Jenayah Sure it was a film. Rented it out the videos shop when going thro a Manga phase. Getting PO'd I can't find it.

Comment: @Seamusthedog alright, was thinking of [_Little Vampire_](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=petit+vampire) but it's not that known, and a series (and probably not translated). Still worth putting it somewhere in a "vampires in space" question... The series is awful, though.

Comment: @Jenayah this was a gore/horror type anime. If only Global Video was still with us!

Answer (score 5):

Honorable mention for [*Lifeforce*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_(film)), a 1985 film about space vampires.

Terran astronauts discover a space ship hundreds of miles long in the wake of Haley's comet. Onboard the spaceship are three naked humanoid aliens suspended in cylinders. Upon return to Earth, the aliens awaken and start feeding on humans. Yum yum.

Unsure about the exploding out the airlock scene.

[image: Lifeforce 1985 movie poster]

Comment: Looks terrible, so bad it could be good but not what I'm thinking about. Mine is an animated film

Comment: Aw, It weren't that bad. I saw it at the cinema when it first came out and then bought the video (VHS) as soon as it was released.         
 In hindsight it weren't that good either!

Comment: There is a scene where someone basically exudes all their blood and that blood forms a human figure that speaks to the protagonists.  This could loosely fit the description of someone exploding and reforming.

Comment: @Jherico Please feel free to upvote. :)

Comment: Will have to check Amazon, would love to see it on VHS to see what trailers are in before it!